# Printing exponential number returned by SCPI command

Tags: python, python-2.7

The documentation of the 'Return Format' of a particular SCPI command says:

> "The reading is in the form `+n.nnnnnnE+nn` for each channel specified.
>   Multiple    responses are separated by commas. Example The following
>   query returns the power measured on channel 1. MEAS:POW? (@1) Typical
>   Response: `+1.000000E+01`"

When I am trying to print the return value of this command with **%e** then it throws an error with invalid syntax.

```
  print "Measured power is : %e\n"  chan_power
```

If I omit %e and just print the variable `chan_power` I get: `-6.319059E-07`

But the documentation as well as the return format shows its an exponential number returned by the command. Can anyone point where I am going wrong?

Comment: I think it should be `print "Measured power is : %e\n"%(chan_power,)`

Answer (score 1):

Your print should be

```
print "Measured power is : %e\n"%(chan_power,)
```

For formatted output, a tuple is expected after `%`. In your case, no tupple is provided. Since, there is `%e`, it needs tuple of one variable.

Comment: Tried your solution...giving an error: TypeError: float argument required, not unicode

Comment: Than you need to convert `chan_power` to float or change %e to %s.

Comment: If you can show the value assigned to `chan_power`, then I can determine exact format.

Comment: I wrote in my question, if I just print chan_power I get the value -6.319059E-07

Comment: You can get -6.31905 in the case of `chan_power = "-6.319"` and `chan_power = -6.319`. Both are different.